# Android Volley + Loader pattern?

Tags: android, android-loader, android-volley

I kinda liked Volley framework, but I still have some doubts about it.

For example, how does Volley line up with Loader pattern? Since it's requests are handled in an async manner, calling it on background doesn't make much sense. On the other hand, if we ignore the Loader pattern, we will cancel the loading and reload the necessary resources, it's kinda waste.

How does Volley framework work with Loaders in Android?

Answer (score 12):

A Loader can encapsulate practically anything, including Volley requests. When your Loader encapsulates a framework that already handles background work for you and calls you back on the main thread, like Volley, your loader implementation must not inherit from `AsyncTaskLoader` but simply from the `Loader` base class. You would then start the Volley request in the `onForceLoad()` method.

When your loader gets the result back on the main thread through a callback, it just needs to push it to the Activity/Fragment by calling `deliverResult()`.

Your loader would also need to keep a reference to the Volley request in progress to be able to cancel it in `onStopLoading()`. onStopLoading() is not called in case of configuration change like screen rotation, only when leaving the Activity.

The only disadvantage is that Loaders don't have a built-in mechanism to propagate errors, while Volley does. So in your Volley error callback inside of your Loader, you'll need to either deliver a null result or send a local broadcast to notify the Activity/Fragment of the error.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK and I have seen in the sources, responses to your requests will be cached, **IF** the server sends the proper caching `headers`(ETag), and the second time you will attempt to make a `GET` request, to the same url, you will be provided with a response from the `cache`, instead of calling the `Network` again.(by default `Volley` caches the requests using as `key` the `URL`).

Adding `Requests` to the `RequestQueue` should be done from the `MainThread`, as it makes no sense to call them from a background `Thread`.

Comment: I was thinking about a situation where user rotates the device while loading. Normal behaviour of Volley framework would be cancelling requests and re-starting them when orientation change is done.Using Loader pattern would protect the state of loading from orientation changes.

Comment: yes. you are correct. there is no straight, out of the box mean to "re-connect" to a pending request, or "keep it" running and get responses on orientation changes/ Activity Stop-Resume.

Comment: It makes sense to call it from a background thread in situations such as loading additional information for a push notification before it displays. However, for general purposes it's better to call it from the main thread.

Answer (score 3):

I just publish an article about Volley and it integration into project over Loader pattern. Advanced approach is shown. Loader states are fully defined and displayed in diagram.

Article: https://plus.google.com/117981280628062796190/posts/8b9RmQvxudb

[image: Loader States Diagram]

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to make synchronous requests with Volley via the RequestFuture class. I haven't looked into this personally, but it looks like you could leverage that with a Loader to get the best of both worlds (Volley's Cache with the loading stability of the Loader).

Comment: This way your `Loader` cannot return both intermediate and final results. `RequestFuture` only returns the first received result (which is intermediate in case you use cache); final result just updates the cache and cannot be propagated to UI.

Comment: Good point. At this point, I would not recommend using loaders at all, I think they have too much overhead and it's better to create your own solution from external libraries such as Retrofit or Volley.

Comment: There is no need for synchronous requests. If you extend `Loader<D>` you are expected to do work in background thread anyway.

Comment: Pius, if you have multiple requests that need to be made, it's much cleaner to do them all in one async thread instead of having to chain callbacks. You actually can't use Volley asynchronously in an AsyncLoader because it throws an error if it's not called from the main thread.